# how i can change square size in CSS with the same class but different div?

Tags: html, css

How can I change image size of second div in CSS changing only square?  with the same class but different div?

```
<div class="square"> <img class="square__img" src="square.png"> </div>
<div class="square square--small"> <img class="square__image" src="square.png"> </div>
```

Comment: With `.square` and `.square.square--small`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    .square {
      width: 300px; /*standard image size*/
    }

    .square.square--small {
      width: 150px; /*small image size*/
    }

    .square.square--small .square__image { /*apply change only to small img*/
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but then the first image changing size as well, but i need to change only the second image

Comment: @MIN I have edited my answer. `.square.square--small .square__image { ... }` should take care of it :)

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use this css selector:

```
.square img
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px
}
.square.square--small img{
   width:50px;
   height:50px
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i have to change square__image, i and i am not sure how to do it

Comment: your welcome ... so i think @Becky answerd correctly....

Answer (score 0):

Make image to not overlap the `div` by setting its `max-width` to `100%`, `max-height` to `100%`
and `height` to `auto` like this:

```css
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: auto;
```

then style your division elements like this for example:

```css
  .square {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 30px;
        }

  .square.square--small {
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
        }
```

Again, width and height are only for demonstration, modify as you like.

Answer (score 0):

[img of working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X334f.png)

```
<div class="square">
  <img class="square__img" src="square.png" alt="img1">
</div>
<div class="square square--small">
  <img alt="img2" class="square__image" src="square.png">
</div>

.square {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.square img {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
.square--small {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.square--small img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```